# IE truncates frame's src due to ampersand encoding

Tags: internet-explorer, frame, src, ampersand, truncated

Never have I felt so alone, lonelier than [this](https://xkcd.com/979/) guy. I found no one having the same problem.

Here's the problem I've been stuck for weeks now. I have the page with a frame in it (also happens with iframe). This frame's src is a long string with multiple url parameters. Some of these parameters are parts of sql query.

Now, what happens is that in IE, in certain combination of these url parameters in frame's src, ampersands (&) get encoded to &amp ; while the length of a src string remains as if they weren't encoded. I.e. the following string:

```
example.html?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

will be transformed into

```
example.html?param1=value1&amp;param2=va
```

and I'll get a blank page.

I've examined the exact url parameters that cause this, but there is nothing special about them. Also, in some combinations they cause the problem, while in other they don't.

I've also examined what I'm sending to IE, and that in not encoded url. I've tried encoding it explicitly, but it still happens.

The problem only occurs on IE (10, 11 and Edge), but not on Firefox or Chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it get transformed into example.html?param1=value1&amp;param2=va or example.html?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2?

Comment: It's transformed to example.html?param1=value1&amp;param2=va. That is the problem, it gets truncated.